# Multisite subdirectory blogs missing slash

Tags: multisite, urls, htaccess, wp-config, site-url

New WordPress 3.5.2 multisite (subdirectory) install is missing a slash when creating new blogs.

WordPress is installed to server like:

> blogs.domain.com

When a new user registers, the conformation email has the URL for their blog like:

> blogs.domain.comnewuser (missing the / between the domain and blog name).

From Network Admin, I can edit the site, adding a `/` to either the end of the Domain field or the begining of the Path field and the site can be accessed:

> blogs.domain.com/newuser

wp-config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Adding `$base = '/';` to wp-config didn't seem to make a difference.

.htaccess:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'blogs.domain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
fine('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

DB:

wp_site has:

> **domain:** blogs.domain.com
>   **path:** /

wp_blogs has:

> **domain:** blogs.domain.com
>   **path:** /

but when a new user/blog is added, `wp_blogs` gets:

> **domain:** blogs.domain.com
>   **path:** user/

Comment: WPMU Ldap Auth plugin is being used also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPMU Ldap Authentication was causing the incorrect URL issue. Disabling the plugin allowed users/sites to be created correctly.

This site has a fix for the plugin that allows it to run properly in WP 3.5.2: http://www.fotan.net/wpmu-ldap-plugin-fixes/

Answer (score -1):

do not blame the .htaccess file.

Edit wpmuldap/lib/wpmu_ldap.functions.php

```
$domain = strtolower( wp_specialchars( $newUserName ) );
    if( constant( "VHOST" ) == 'yes' ) {
        $newdomain = $domain . "." . $current_site->domain;
        $path = '/' . $base;
    }
    else {
        $newdomain = $current_site->domain;
        $path = '/' . $base . $domain . '/';
    }
```

Notice that I modified the $path variable adding a leading / using: " '/' . "
Right after that everything works fine.

I am using WP 3.9.1 with WPMU Ldap Authentication ver 4.0.2 using "Network" mode.

Comment: **NEVER** change core files or theme/plugin files if you are not the author